Gradio.load not working correctly with textArea
I have the following script, I intend for testing purposes that whenever I click the button, it changes the value of interactive for the text component, however I cannot seem to be able to interact with it when in browser, any help ?
Here is a code to reproduce the problem
import gradio as gr

ACTIVATED = False
def set_interactive( *args, **kwargs):
    global ACTIVATED
    return gr.update(
        interactive = ACTIVATED,
    )

def flip_state():
    global ACTIVATED
    ACTIVATED = not ACTIVATED


with gr.Blocks() as training_interface:

    sample_text_box = gr.TextArea(
        interactive=True,
    )

    activating_button = gr.Button(
        interactive=True,
    )

    activating_button.click(flip_state)
    training_interface.load(set_interactive, outputs=sample_text_box, every=1)
training_interface.launch()

